# angular js :click event for quantity increase and decrease button inside products list build with ng-repeat reflecting each list quantity number

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, parent-child, product-quantity

I am having issue with the product list quantity buttons. I am new to angular js and trying to build product list which is having quantity increase and decrease button. I have build the list with ng-repeat, for increase and decrease button i am calling a function qty_incr() and qty_decr() it works but reflecting on every list item. I want to reflect only the same product. The same thing with jquery can done like this

```
$('.qty_incr').click(function(){
```

$(this).parents('.cart_product').children('#incr_decr_no').text(parseInt($(this).parents('.cart_product').children('#incr_decr_no').text() + 1));

```
})
```

Wondering how could same can achieve with angularjs, here is my code

```
<p ng-show="loading" class="loading"><img src="assets/img/Spinner-1s-200px.gif" width="50" /></p>
<div class="cart_products" ng-hide="loading" ng-repeat="product in data.products">
<div class="cart_product">
    <div class="cart_pro_img"><img src="{{product.product_image}}" /></div>
    <div class="cart_pro_detail">
        <div class="cart_pro_title">{{product.product_name}}</div>
        <div class="cart_pro_price">₹ {{product.price}}</div>
        <div class="cart_pro_incr_decr">

                <i class="fa fa-minus-circle" ng-click="qty_decr($parent.item)" style="color:#FF4646"></i>    
                <span id="incr_decr_no" ng-init="$parent.item.quantity=1">{{item.quantity}}</span>
                <i class="fa fa-plus-circle" ng-click="qty_incr()" style="color:#68C549"></i>  
                <i class="fa fa-times-circle-o" {{item.product_id}}></i>   
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
app.controller("cart", function($scope, $http){     
var guestid = localStorage.getItem('guestid');
$scope.loading = true;
$http.get(baseurl+"webservice.php?req=cartproducts&guestid="+guestid)
.then(function(response){
    $scope.loading = false;
    $scope.data = response.data;
    //console.log($scope.data);
    //$rootScope.cartcount(guestid); 
});
$scope.qty_incr = function(item){
    $scope.item.quantity = $scope.item.quantity + 1;
}
$scope.qty_decr = function(item){
    if($scope.item.quantity > 1){
        $scope.item.quantity = $scope.item.quantity - 1;
    }

}

})
```

Comment: Pass $index to your function like ng-click="qty_decr($parent.item, $index)" and assign the index position to your scope like $scope.item.quantity[index] = Your value;

Comment: @SudhirOjha not worked

Comment: Please provide your code in plunker or fiddle.

Comment: `$scope.qty_incr = function(item) {    var index = $scope.data.indexOf(item);    $scope.data[index].quantity = $scope.data[index].quantity + 1;
}` and the same with `-1` in decrement function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it by modifying the html and js code

My HTML

```
<div class="cart_products" ng-hide="loading" ng-repeat="product in data.products">
<div class="cart_product">
    <div class="cart_pro_img"><img src="{{product.product_image}}" /></div>
    <div class="cart_pro_detail">
        <div class="cart_pro_title">{{product.product_name}}</div>
        <div class="cart_pro_price">₹ {{product.price}}</div>
        <div class="cart_pro_incr_decr">

                <i class="fa fa-minus-circle" ng-click="qty_decr(item)" style="color:#FF4646"></i>    
                <span id="incr_decr_no" ng-init="item.quantity=1">{{item.quantity}}</span>
                <i class="fa fa-plus-circle" ng-click="qty_incr(item)" style="color:#68C549"></i>  
                <i class="fa fa-times-circle-o" ng-click="removefromcart(product.product_id)"></i>   
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and JS is:

```
app.controller("cart", function($scope,$rootScope, $http){     
var guestid = localStorage.getItem('guestid');

$http.get(baseurl+"webservice.php?req=cartproducts&guestid="+guestid)
    .then(function(response){
        $scope.data = response.data;
        console.log($scope.data);

    })


$scope.qty_incr = function(item){
    item.quantity = item.quantity + 1;
}
$scope.qty_decr = function(item){
    if(item.quantity > 1){
       item.quantity = item.quantity - 1;
    }

}

})
```